# Why does Angular $resource add parameters twice, in some cases?

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

This code:

```
var CompanyRecruiters = $resource('/admin/companies/:id/recruiters.json', {id: '@id'});

// create a new employee
var employeeResource = new CompanyRecruiters(); 

employeeResource.employee = {name: "dwq", email: "dwq@wq.com", role: "Admin"};

var saveEmployeePromise = employeeResource.$save({id: companyId});
```

NB: Recruiter and Employee is equivalent in this case. It's really supposed to be called Employee all over, but it currently goes to the Recruiters controller on the server. It hasn't been refactored into the Employee controller on the server yet.

Sends the following parameters to the server, when the promise is executed:

> Started POST "/admin/companies/2/recruiters.json" for 127.0.0.1 at
>   2014-08-15 13:49:08 +0200 Processing by
>   Admin::RecruitersController#create as JSON   Parameters:
>   {**"employee"=>{"name"=>"dwq", "email"=>"dwq@wq.com", "role"=>"Admin"}**,
>   "company_id"=>"2", "recruiter"=>{**"employee"=>{"name"=>"dwq",
>   "email"=>"dwq@wq.com", "role"=>"Admin"}**}}

Notice that the parameters are sent twice, and one of them is wrapped in a `"recruiter"=>{` hash.

But if I simply change one of the lines to:

> employeeResource.**recruiter** = {name: "dwq", email: "dwq@wq.com", role:
>   "Admin"};

Then it sends the following parameters to the server:

> Started POST "/admin/companies/2/recruiters.json" for 127.0.0.1 at
>   2014-08-15 13:57:24 +0200 Processing by
>   Admin::RecruitersController#create as JSON   Parameters:
>   {"recruiter"=>{"name"=>"dwq", "email"=>"dwq@wq.com",
>   "role"=>"Admin"}, "company_id"=>"2"}

Which only sends the parameters once, like it seems it should.

Why does Angular $resource behave in this way?

Answer (score 1):

It's not Angular doing this, but Rails. You probably have

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
  wrap_parameters format: [:json] if respond_to?(:wrap_parameters)
end
```

in config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb.